# Unable to record and stream screen with ffmpeg

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg

I am using RPI 2 and trying to record a screen and stream it on udp using ffmpeg.
I tried the following lines

> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="Stereo Mix (IDT High Definition" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -r 10 -async 1 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 24k -ar 22050 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 5000k -f mpegts udp://239.0.1.23:1234

But I am getting error.

> The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
>   in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
>   incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
>   (see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
>
> Unknown input format: 'video4linux2'

I also tried x11grab but still getting the same error.

Please help!

Comment: How about the quoted `avconv` program that is suggested?

Comment: As @SlySven suggested, I tried avconv and it is working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: How about writing it up as an answer and then accepting it?  That way this doesn't float around as another unanswered question, the fact that you found you could record a screen and stream it on UDP may be useful for someone else...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled ffmpeg. Doing that, x11grab error was resolved but i faced lot more issues after that. Finally I move to avconv and used the following line to stream desktop recording:

> avconv -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1920x540 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -an udp://239.0.1.23:1234?buffer_size=10000B/a.avi

The links, I used for reference are,

[For streaming](https://libav.org/avconv.html#udp)

[For recording](http://www.tecmint.com/record-ubuntu-desktop-screen-using-avconv/)